# Dash Online Search Not Working

Tags: unity, unity-dash

I know 99% of comments are about disabling this feature, but there are times where having a direct link to something online would be useful. I have System Settings>Security & Privacy > Search > Include online search results set to ON, I have rebooted; I have reinstalled unity-scope-home (it was already installed); I have online search set to ON in unity-tweak-tool; I have selected "More suggestions" and "Web" from the Categories; Amazon, ebay, wikipedia are selected in sources. As a test, if I type "turtle" in and have "more suggestions", "reference", and "web" as Categories and amazon, dictionary, ebay, and wikipedia as sources, I get nothing. I am using the "home" icon at the bottom of the dash. I am using 14.04 LTS.

[list of installed unity-scope packages](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ozrawgqz1gk9sje/unity_scope_list.png?dl=0/%22list%20of%20installed%20unity-scope%20packages%22)

I am not sure what most of these do. Could some of them be creating conflicts with the default configuration?